# how to use subprocess in notebook?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, subprocess

I want to use `subprocess` in kaggle notebook, kaggle notebook is very similar to jupyter notebook.

When I use the following code I got 0.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("ls")
```

What I want is the list of the files in current folder.

Could you help me please?

Comment: That is the return code of the command and the expected result. There are other functions in the `subprocess` module that will return other information. Also consider using `os.listdir(path)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.But I want to perform other linux commands...for example,git command in notebook.So I want such a python package to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. I can't explain it because I don't know what know anything about the subprocess library but it worked from my jupyter notebook when I tried it. I figured it out from this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56138384/8164908). However, I couldn't get it to work when I did something like "ls -a".

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen('ls',
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)


with process.stdout:
    for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''):
        print(line.decode().strip())
```

### ***A Better Alternative if the Kaggle notebook has the same functionality as Jupyter notebook.***

In Jupyter notebooks, you can execute commands by prepending `!` before the command in a jupyter notebook cell. For example, you can clone a github repo from the cell with this command `!git clone https_repo_here`. In my subprocess example above, I couldn't get `ls -a` to work but I can get it to work just by using `!ls -a` in the Jupyter notebook cell.

Another helpful tip in Jupyter notebook is `%`. I don't know all the functionality of this thing (I think it's called a magic symbol) but I know that you can, for example, change the working directory of you notebook just by writing `%cd different_directory_here`. I don't know why but if you wrote `!cd different_directory_here`, it won't permanently change the working directory of your Jupyter notebook.